# Cowgill's law in satem languages

Tags: germanic-languages

I had discovered a new law.
I named it "Russian law".
You may rename it as is good in your eyes.
It says that a PIE laryngeal /h₃/, and possibly /h₂/, turns into /z/ in Satem languages. (compare Cowgill's law + Grimm's law + satemization).
People before me thought, that zn' is isolated Slavic suffix. It is wrong.
The first part /z/ is a laryngal. The correct unisolated suffixe is n'.
Examples:
жизнь (ži**z**nʹ) a life PIE gʷey**h₃**-.
болезнь (bolé**z**nʹ) a disease PIE bʰel**h**₂-
and so on
You are to bring it to mind.
I want go to bed.
Examples of simple satemization
Proto-Slavic ***z**ǫbъ PGmc ***k**ambaz
Proto-Slavic ***z**ьrno PGmc ***k**urną
Proto-Slavic ***z**nati PGmc ***k**nāan
Proto-Slavic *(j)azъ PGmc *ek
Proto-Slavic *melzivo PGmc *meluks

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: This isn't an appropriate place to submit new linguistics research. If you are confident in your law, please write it up and submit it to a linguistics journal.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there's a serious problem with your new "sound law".
Apparently, bolezn' is derived from the verb bol-et' and there's no *H2 in that root *bol- < *bhol- plus the stative -eH1- "to be sick, painful".
How do you explain that the verb zhit' "to live" from the same root has no -z-?
What are the conditions of your "sound law"? When does it occur?

Comment: The verb form  doesn't have a sonorant.
see also
боязнь *bojaznь fear bʰeyh₂-.
How does cowgill's law explain that the Gothic qius "alive" from the root *kwikwaz has no -k-?
I don't realy have enough time to complex analysis. 
I don't know precise conditions of the law.
I spend a fair amount of time to formulate answer in English.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/bolěti. Possibly from Proto-Indo-European *bʰleh₂w- (Ancient Greek φλαῦρος (phlaûros, “bad, inferior”), Old Norse blauðr (“timid”)) alongside *bʰelh₂-.

Comment: I believe this at least deserves the attention of specialists.

Comment: Slavic bol-et' cannot derive from *bhleH2w- * obviously *. It derives from *bhol- plus a stative suffix -eH1-.